# kubernetes cronjob in GKE stop scheduling the job after a few weeks

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have this yaml for cronjob, running in google kubernetes engine:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2019-04-22T18:20:51Z
  name: cron-field-velocity-field-details-manager
  namespace: master
  resourceVersion: "73643714"
  selfLink: /apis/batch/v1beta1/namespaces/master/cronjobs/cron-field-velocity-field-details-manager
  uid: 5be9e8d5-652b-11e9-bf91-42010a9600af
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          creationTimestamp: null
          labels:
            app: cron-field-velocity-field-details-manager
            chart: field-velocity-field-details-manager-0.0.1
            heritage: Tiller
            release: master-field-velocity-field-details-manager
        spec:
          containers:
          - args:
            - ./field-velocity-field-details-manager.dll
            command:
            - dotnet
            image: taranisag/field-velocity-field-details-manager:master.993b179
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            name: cron-field-velocity-field-details-manager
            resources:
              requests:
                cpu: "2"
                memory: 2Gi
            terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
            terminationMessagePolicy: File
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
          imagePullSecrets:
          - name: regsecret
          restartPolicy: Never
          schedulerName: default-scheduler
          securityContext: {}
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  schedule: '* 2,14 * * *'
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  suspend: false
status:
  lastScheduleTime: 2019-06-20T02:00:00Z
```

It was working for a few weeks meaning the job was running twice a day, but it stop running a week ago.

There was no indication of an error and the last run was completed successfully

Is it something in the yaml I defined wrong ?

Comment: Config looks fine. Can you check cluster events (they should be exported to stackdriver) to see if there is an issue with scheduling? Maybe a new workload has been deployed and since then there are no longer enough resources to schedule the cronjob pods?

Comment: Also, have you made any changes to the cluster? Master or node pool upgrades? New workloads? Changes to running workloads? Etc